# post view counter function returns user_id error laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement some basic viewcounter to my laravel project. For some reason it returns an odd error:General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value. No when I remove the function from the model. The show page works, so I don't see why it is telling me user_id doesn't have a default value, neither why this functions won't work properly

the table:

```
 Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
            $table->bigInteger('reads')->unsigned()->default(0)->index();
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

the function in the post model:

```
 public function incrementReadCount() {
        $this->increment('reads');
        return $this->save();
    }
```

The function before returnin the show view:

```
  public function mount($slug)
    {
        $this->post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    }

    public function render(Post $post)
    {
        $post->incrementReadCount();
        return view('livewire.post-show')->layout('layouts.guest');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling the `save` method after incrementing, Laravel will try to create a new post record, but without providing a `user_id`. (hence the "Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value" error). You don't want to create a new record.

Just remove the `save()` call from the `incrementReadCount` method:

```
public function incrementReadCount() 
{
    $this->increment('reads');
}
```